# Event firing constantly on Android Emulator and on some physical devices

Tags: android, xamarin.android, async-await, eventhandler

I have Android Emulator running with Visual Studio and a physical device Nokia 5 with Android 8.1. On both devices following event is firing constantly:

```
private async void InputField_KeyPressEditorAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var ke = e as View.KeyEventArgs;
        var eae = e as TextView.EditorActionEventArgs;

        if (ke != null)
        {
            ke.Handled = false;
        }

        if (eae != null)
        {
            eae.Handled = false;
        }

        if (ke != null && (ke.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down ) &&
            (ke.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter ) ||
            eae != null && eae.ActionId == ImeAction.Done)
        {
            // some logic
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //.

            await ScanTu();

            // more logic
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //.
            //.

            if (ke != null)
            {
                ke.Handled = true;
            }

            if (eae != null)
            {
                eae.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(
            this,
            $"Method {new StackTrace(ex).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name} threw error: {ex}",
            Log.DEBUG_LEVELS.ERROR);
    }
}
```

When I run the code on physical device M3SM10 barcode scanner with Android 4.3 I cannot reproduce the issue. There is AlertDialog being shown on `ScanTu()` when there's no connection and user must click **OK** to retry the operation. Maybe this is where event fires again?

Comment: What does this piece of code do?

Comment: Could you please post more details of your code? so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I found that the event was firing because of clicking on the OK button or inside the input field. So I disable the input field at the beginning of the event handler code and enable it back before exiting the method. Seems to work so far.